# Open IOS App Using URL Scheme and Pass Data For Registration

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have implemented URL Scheme in my App so that whenever i click the URL, it will open up my app. I have also inserted some request in the URL such as

`Yuvtime//:?registerName=Puppy&Passwords=67825`

and i use the openUrl in AppDelegate to handle the processing of the URL and pass the data (registerName=Puppy&Passwords=67825`) to my rootViewController which is the registration page of my app, the code is as shown below.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
    // Check the calling application Bundle ID
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"yuvitime"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication);
        NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
        self.yuvitimeRequest = [url query];
        NSLog(@"URL query: %@", yuvitimeRequest);

        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
```

And in the RegistrationviewController, I implemented the code as follows.

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    AppDelegate * myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.requestFromURL = myAppDelegate.yuvitimeRequest;
    NSLog(@"%@ hello google", self.requestFromURL);
    if (self.requestFromURL.length > 0){
        self.isRequestFromURL = YES;
    }
    if(self.isRequestFromURL == YES){
        self.mainViewController.joinRoomName = self.requestFromURL;
        self.isRequestFromURL = NO;
        self.requestFromURL = @"";
        [self presentViewController:self.mainViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

However, the problem i encounter is that:

If the user already has its app opened, this viewWilAppear in the RegistrationViewController will not be called again, so the data will not be passed automatically from the URL. (Only by killing the app, and click the URL will the data be passed as what we initially desired).

I also understand that when an App is already open and called again, only

```
(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application &
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

will be called in sequence in the app delegate. But somehow i stuck on how do i pass data to my registrationViewController from these two methods and if i can manage to do it in these two application methods, that would mean that my app checks every time on whether there is any registration data available from URL when the app comes to the foreground.

Since we already have the

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

to handle the URL scheme, is it possible that we only check once without using the foreground and didBecomeActive app delegate functions when we click the URL?

**EDIT**: After implementing URL scheme, whenever you click a URL, a delegate method in AppDelegate.m will be triggered.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;
```

This is also the function that will enable us to process the URL in our app and pass it around to other viewControllers.

I was kinda thinking, is there a way that we can implement a notification/function such that only when this  openURL function is called, we then call the triggerURL function in registrationViewController.

Just out of curiosity!

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `RegistrationViewController`, you can register for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and get notified of application being awakened even when your view controller was already loaded.

Add this line in your `loadView`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(triggerURL) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

This will allow the function updateSettings to be called every time your app wakes. Also remember to remove this listener at the end by:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

in your `dealloc` method.

Post that, this is how your `viewWillAppear` & `triggerURL` will look like:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self triggerURL];
}


- (void)triggerURL {
    AppDelegate * myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.requestFromURL = myAppDelegate.yuvitimeRequest;
    NSLog(@"%@ hello google", self.requestFromURL);

    if (self.requestFromURL.length > 0){
        self.isRequestFromURL = YES;
    }

    if(self.isRequestFromURL == YES){
        self.mainViewController.joinRoomName = self.requestFromURL;
        self.isRequestFromURL = NO;
        self.requestFromURL = @"";
        [self presentViewController:self.mainViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, i tried it out and it worked, but i have a few more questions to ask. By doing the method you recommend, my app checks URL every time i switched to my app. You see, when the URL is clicked, the {{{(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation}}}} app delegate method is called. How do i create a notification so that whenever this function is triggered, it will send a notification to registrationViewController like the example above? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry but I really couldn't quite get what you mentioned. Could you please simplify and edit your question with details of what you want. One thing - the notification I suggested is triggered every time you go background and come foreground. Let me know what is your expectation.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. I have updated the post with the question under EDIT.. I know i may sound a bit confusing here, but it is ok if you won't answer that since it is just out of own personal curiosity to learn. Once again, thank you and appreciate your input!

Comment: I see. Yes, that is also possible. All you need to do is to fire a local notification. Here is a good [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) on how to do this. For the benefit of others, could you please accept this answer as it has resolved what you were looking for.